# std::bind and std::function term does not evalue as taking 0 arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std-function, stdbind

I'm working on generic class that will be used to run functions of different prototype for performance testing of algorithms.

I stuck because `std::function` can't execute what it was bound with, here is sample code, with comment where the error happens:

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<typename ReturnType>
class Performance
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    using Algorithm = std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>;

    template<typename... Params>
    void run(const Algorithm<Params...>& ref, const Algorithm<Params...>& target)
    {
        // ERROR: term does not evaluate as taking 0 args
        ref();
        target();
    }
};

void bar1(int, int)
{
    // algorithm 1
}

void bar2(int, int)
{
    // algorithm 2
}

int main()
{
    using test = Performance<void>;
    using Algorithm = test::Algorithm<int, int>;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;

    Algorithm ref = std::bind(bar1, std::ref(x), std::ref(y));
    Algorithm target = std::bind(bar2, std::ref(x), std::ref(y));

    test foobar;

    foobar.run(ref, target);
}
```

Comment: Both are supposed to take two `int`s, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, and they have been bound with `int`s with `std::bind`, to me it looks like `std::bind` does nothing here, Is there alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, the `std::function` type, i.e. `Algorithm` is declared to take two parameters (with type `int`); when calling on them two arguments are required.

After `std::bind` applied, the returned functors take no parameters; arguments (`std::ref(x)` and `std::ref(y)`) have been bound. `Algorithm` should be declared as

```
using Algorithm = test::Algorithm<>;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PHfhq2oZ21H8H48q)

Comment: @metablaster It might be confusing because you can set the functor returned from `std::bind` which takes nothing to `std::function` which is declared to take two `int`s. `std::function` takes type-erase trait. BTW: If you try to pass two `int`s in your original code, you'll find it could compile but the passed `int`s are not used at all. The bound arguments are used. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z249vHyDDd4BcG3M)